# React dropzone. Add files to state instead of overwriting them

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

Why can't I use setImages like this. I works like this `setImages([...images, acceptedFiles[0])` and like this `setImages(acceptedFiles)`. I don't get what the problem is.

```
const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
        noClick:true,
        accept: "image/*",
        onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
            acceptedFiles.map((file:any, index:number) => Object.assign(file, {
                preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
            }))
            setImages([...images, acceptedFiles])
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use previous state value. e.g, setState((prev) => something);

`setImages((images) => [...images, acceptedFiles])`

Comment: where is the difference to `setImages([...images, acceptedFiles])`. I tried it before and it doesn't make a difference in the result

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue, why this isn't working and I am hoping for someone to explain that, but it works with `setImages(images.concat(acceptedFiles))`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).